# Android variable never used

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

After creating my activity, I get this warning:

> Variable 'station' is never used

I not certain as to what that warning means nor how to fix it. I'm guessing the 'station' variable hasn't been declared however I don't know the correct way to declare it. All help would be appreciated.

**FragmentWCLine.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentWCLine extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "Station_key";

    private class WC {
        private CharSequence station;
        private CharSequence zone;
        private Class<? extends Activity> activityClass;
        private Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass;

        public WC(int stationResId, int zoneResId, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass, Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass) {
            this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
            this.activityClass = activityClass;
            this.station = getResources().getString(stationResId);
            this.zone = getResources().getString(zoneResId);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return station.toString(); }
        public String getzone(){ return zone.toString(); }
    }

    private static WC[] mWC;

    private boolean mTwoPane;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wc_line, container, false);

        // Instantiate the list of stations.
        mWC = new WC[]{
                new WC(R.string.bank, R.string.zone_1, WCBankActivity.class, FragmentWCBank.class),
                new WC(R.string.wat, R.string.zone_1, WCWATActivity.class, FragmentWCWAT.class)
        };

        final ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_wc);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mWC));
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(mTwoPane){

                    setItemNormal();
                    View rowView = view;
                    setItemSelected(rowView);
                }
                else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), mWC[position].activityClass);
                    String station = mWC[position].station.toString();
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, station);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

            public void setItemSelected(View view){
                View rowView = view;
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66CCCC"));

                TextView tv0 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station);
                tv0.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));

                TextView tv1 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone);
                tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
            }

            public void setItemNormal()
            {
                for (int i=0; i< listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View v = listView.getChildAt(i);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                    TextView tv0 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station));
                    tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    TextView tv1 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone));
                    tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B5B5B5"));
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    static class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView station;
            TextView zone;
        }

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        WC[] mWC;

        public MyAdapter(Context contexts, WC[] samples) {
            this.mWC = samples;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexts);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mWC.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mWC[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        /**set selected position**/
        private int selectPosition = -1;
        public void setSelectPosition(int position){
            if(position!=selectPosition){
                selectPosition = position;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_dualline, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.station = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station);
                viewHolder.zone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.station.setText(mWC[position].station);
            viewHolder.zone.setText(mWC[position].getzone());

            //change item color
            if(position==selectPosition){
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
                viewHolder.station.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
            }else {

            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

**WCBankActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;


public class WCBankActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "Station_key";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_wc_bank);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Get the message from the intent
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            // Notice to specify the sender Activity for the message
            String station = intent.getStringExtra(WCBankActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

            FragmentWCBank newFragment = new FragmentWCBank();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**FragmentWCBank.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentWCBank extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wc_bank, container, false);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that code doesn't corresponded to the possible error.

Comment: where are you getting this error? in the logcat? if yes, please post the logcat too..

Comment: Not in the log cat. The text turns grey.

Comment: There is a variable called `station` that you might have declared, or the class you're extending declared it but is never used. You could try doing a search for it, it should only be a warning and not an error.

Comment: It should be a warning then...not an error...its because you havent used it after initialising..its quite normal..

Comment: It is actually a warning. Apologies for the confusion. Code has been updated.

Comment: `String station = intent.getStringExtra(WCBankActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);` you declare and intitialize it but don't use it. Use it, delete it, or walk away. It's just a warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is a Warning rather than an Error. The difference being a Warning will not prevent your program from running, but an Error would.

The warning you are seeing is due to the fact that you are declaring a variable `station` but then never using it. Your IDE is smart enough to notice this and is trying to warn you as a reminder that you aren't using the variable that you created.

In this case it's this line:

```
String station = intent.getStringExtra(WCBankActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

You declare a variable `station` and give it a value but then you never read that value or do anything else with it. Therefore you could theoretically remove the variable with no other impact to your app.